# Android receiver works dynamically but not via manifest file

Tags: android

I have a broadcast receiver that works when I set it up dynamically, but does not work when declared in a manifest file.

I've googled for this and all the examples match what I'm doing in my code. I do have an activity in my manifest file, so that can't be the problem. I've tried fully specifying the receiver class name as well as using .MyBroadcastReceiver but that did not make any difference.

Can someone help?

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mikrodyne.receiverdemo" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.mikrodyne.receiverdemo.MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is my receiver class

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d("Receiver", "Received action: " + action);
    }
}
```

TIA
Nisha Miller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation for HEADSET_PLUG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG):

> You *cannot* receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with [Context.registerReceiver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)).

So what you're trying to do is not possible.

Comment: Thank you! I missed that part of the documentation :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get events from outside, you need to set `android:exported="true"`

Note: you can't get that intent.

Put this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.mikrodyne.receiverdemo.MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```